# Is't possible to get access to <ul> and <li> during submiting form

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, jquery-mobile

I have view with controller. I would like to know if it is possible to get access to ul and li? I don't want to do ajax call and pass these elements as parameters. Li elements are added on client side dynamically. this.Request.Form show me only 'name' variable without 'list'. Any advices?

```
<form action="@Url.Action("Filter")" method="POST">

    <ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true" data-filter="false" name="list">
        @foreach (var item in @Model.Items)
        {
            <li value="@item">@item</li>   
        }
    </ul>

    <input type="text" name="name"/>  

    <inpu type="submit" value="Filter"/>
</form>
```

and controller:

```
  [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Filter(string name, List<string> list)
    {
      // working with list 
      return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
```

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No,

It is not possible to access `<ul>` and `<li>` on post back.

BTW, the following code is generates `<li>` on server not on client

```
 @foreach (var item in @Model.Items)
    {
        <li value="@item">@item</li>   
    }
```

If you wish to access Items (`@item`) on server, there are other ways to get those that do not require access to `<ul>` or `<li>`

For instance, you can emit a hidden (`@Html.HiddenFor`) element in each `<li>` in your loop.

Comment: Thanks, but one question. If item was added dynamically and i want to see this item on server I must use ajax call with post. Right?

Comment: Not necessarily, you can always use '<form>' post method to post values to server.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following.

I'm not sure what your view model looks like, but it seems like a list of string values? So then it will look like this in your view model:

```
public class YourViewModel
{
     public List<string> Items { get; set; }
}
```

In your view try the following:

```
<ul>
     @for (int i = 0; i < Model.Items.Count(); i++)
     {
          <li>
               @Html.DisplayFor(x => x.Items[i])
               @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.Items[i])
          </li>
     }
</ul>
```

When you post then these items should still be in the list.

It might not be a perfect solution but it can guide you on the right track.

I hope this helps.